# Validators array work only first time with asp.net gridview IN GOOGLE CHROME?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, validation, datagridview

I noticed it works perfectly in Internet explorer, but not in Google Chrome!

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Button saveBtn = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnSave");
            CompareValidator validatorNow = (CompareValidator)e.Row.FindControl("DateValidator1");

            saveBtn.ValidationGroup = "mygroupnow" + e.Row.RowIndex;
            validatorNow.ValidationGroup = "mygroupnow" + e.Row.RowIndex;

            saveBtn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "AllValidators('"+ e.Row.RowIndex + "');");
         }

     }
```

I have a gridview with a template, one column has a textbox with validator, and there's a column with a 'save' submit button. I give them a mutual validationGroup name using their row index. I also have update panel on my page, so until now the only way I could disable/enable a button after validating was with javascript. so I created the following method, to check on client click if the validator is valid:

```
function AllValidators(index) {
    var currentValidationGroup = 'mygroupnow' + index;
    for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
        if (i == index) { if (Page_Validators[i].validationGroup == currentValidationGroup) { ValidatorValidate(Page_Validators[i], currentValidationGroup); 
        if (Page_Validators[i].isvalid) { alert('Validated!'); } else {alert('not Valid'); } } }
    }
 }
```

Now, this works great, but only for the first index... index 0, when i = 0, then the alerts really go off according to if it is validated or not, but for the other gridview rows, it just always returns 'Validated', even when it is not. I don't understand whats wrong, the code clearly works since it works the first time, so why not the others too?

and the gridview code :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  runat="server"  DataSourceID="ds_OpenOrders" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Grid_SelectedIndexChanged"  
            onrowcreated="GridView1_RowCreated" CssClass="gridBx" 
            onprerender="GridView1_PreRender" onrowupdated="GridView1_RowUpdated" 
            onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
            onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" CellPadding="3" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="true" DataKeyNames ="RschEstTime,DRNLoanNumber"  PageSize="8" Width="859px" ShowFooter="True">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White"/>
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Est Return Date" SortExpression="RschEstDate" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtReturnDate1" runat="server" TabIndex="1" Text='<%# Bind("RschEstDate", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>' Width="70px" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="GlobalControl_Changed"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CompareValidator ID="DateValidator1" runat="server" Type="Date" Operator="DataTypeCheck" ErrorMessage="Wrong Format" ControlToValidate="txtReturnDate1" Text="*" Display="Static" EnableClientScript="true"></asp:CompareValidator>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TemplateField
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CommandName="Update"  CausesValidation="true" OnClick="MyBtnClick"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

I've also tried doing simpler action in javascript, without the whole loop of Page_validators, and just tried this :

```
function NextTry(validationName) {
    if (Page_ClientValidate(validationName)) { alert('yesss'); } else { alert('noooo'); }
}
```

or

```
function NextTry(index) {
    if(Page_ClientValidate('mygroupnow' + index)) { alert('Valid!');} else { alert('Not Valid'); } }
}
```

and again, same problem, it works for the first row, index 0, it alerts really according to that row validation, for the others, it always returns 'Valid', even when it is not.

Comment: can u please post the gridview code?? I think the prob is with your looping. You have only 1 validator. So, it'll be stored in Page_Validator[0] only. Try looping through grid rows, and then check the validation inside the loop. I can help further if you post your gridview code.

Comment: it does recognize the validators, since it does enter in the loop to the selected validator, only problem is it returns isvalid as true , always, in case helps you here's the grid partial code, there are other irelevant fields.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it. But, a similar code works for my project.

```
    function AllValidators(index) {
        var currentValidationGroup = 'mygroupnow' + index;
       $("#<%=gdRows.ClientID%> tr").each(function() {
           for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
              if (i == index) { if (Page_Validators[i].validationGroup == currentValidationGroup) { ValidatorValidate(Page_Validators[i], currentValidationGroup); 
              if (Page_Validators[i].isvalid) { alert('Validated!'); } else {alert('not Valid'); } } }
           }
        }
     }
```

loop through your gridview rows individually and check the validators.. A similar example is addressed [here](http://techstep.co.in/2013/08/find-controls-inside-grid-view-using-jquery-2/).

Comment: I've tried that, and it doesnt enter the loop anymore, no alert pops

Comment: Is it necessary that you perform this function in javascript? Why not C#?

Comment: yes absolutely, I am doing this in order to disable the button if clicked and valid, meaning not disable if not valid, and in C# code behind it wont apply in any method outside 'Pre_Render' for instance, I've tried at row command, button click, to do button.enabled = false, it wont apply. only in javascript functions who were assigned in row data bound , then the button listens..